# school tuition and being an Oni

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, yeshiva-school

In relation to paying one's children's Yeshiva tuition, when is one permitted to request a discount etc.?

What is the definition of "oni" (poor person) in this situation?

At what point is the community obligated to donate to cover a person's tuition bill?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Pinchos, and thanks for the question! I edited it a bit for style; if there's anything you don't like, feel free to [edit] again.

Comment: I would assume "if one cannot afford it" is a sensible criteria. (Of course, if one spends on vacations and anything else beyond bare necessities, and then asks for charity (tuition discounts) then one's moral compass may need tuning.)